# Formatting matrix data for ANOVAN in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of data values that looks a bit like this, though significantly larger (2000+ rows, 30+ columns):

```
NaN   12   3   NaN   18   NaN   42   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN...
68    NaN  14  Nan   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN   26 ...
...
```

So you see that is largely populated by NaN values. What I am interested in, naturally, are the cells that are populated by values.

I want to be able to run anovan on this data set, and unfortunately it is too large to reformat by hand. What I want to do is have a script run through the matrix, find every value that is not NaN and its index in the matrix, and create three arrays for the anovan input:

Values=[ 12 3 18 42 68 14 26 ...]

Rows= [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...]

Columns= [ 2 3 5 7 1 3 11 ...]

The rows and columns correspond to raters and ratees in a study, which is why they it is so important for me to preserve the exact index of each value.

I cannot figure out how to do this, though.

I have tried using find, but can't get it to do what I want.

```
[r c v] = find(~isnan(datamatrix)) %% doesn't work
```

EDIT: It occurs to me I could just do:

```
[r c v] = find(datamatrix)
```

This will include all of the NaN values, in the [r c v] output, though. In that situation, how would I go through the V array and delete the NaN values AND their corresponding R and C values?

EDIT2: Scratch that. I forgot that some of my values are 0, so I can't use the FIND command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract all the non-NaN numbers and their indices from data matrix like this:

```
i = find(~isnan(datamatrix)); 
values = datamatrix(i);
[rows,columns] = ind2sub(size(datamatrix),i);
```

For the example data you included, this results in:

```
rows' = [2   1   1   2   1   1   2]
columns' = [ 1    2    3    3    5    7   11]
values' = [68   12    3   14   18   42   26]
```

That's all the indices and all their corresponding values.  If you need them ordered in a particular way you'll have to do that seperately.

Comment: Ah, I knew I was getting close to figuring it out, but I didn't know about the ind2sub command! Thanks!